# Retrieving the next item in an array by index in Angular 11

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a list of employees in a JSON object in my service.ts file. It will be moved to a DB eventually. I know this is not the place for it. It's just for dev purposes. I am able to retrieve the employees by clicking on it and displaying them in a dynamic view component.

However, I want to be able to see the next employee on a button click without having to always go back to the main list. I am able to retrieve the index and increment the index on click. I just can't get the route to display the data *for that* index.

The HTML is pretty basic a simple button with a click method. The Service file looks like this:

```
import {HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Employee } from '../models/employee.models';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EmployeesService {

  private listEmployees: Employee[] = [...regular json object...];
  
  constructor() { }

  getEmployees(): Employee[] {
    return this.listEmployees;
  }

  getEmployee(id: number): Employee {    
    return this.listEmployees.find(e => e.id === id);  
  }
}
```

And my employee.component.ts file

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { EmployeesService } from './../../../services/employees.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Employee } from 'src/app/models/employee.models';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'employee',
  templateUrl: './employee.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employee.component.scss']
})
export class EmployeeComponent implements OnInit {

  employee: Employee;
  employees: Employee[];
  index: number;
  private _id: number;

  constructor(
    private _route: ActivatedRoute,
    private _router: Router,
    private _employeeService: EmployeesService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.employees = this._employeeService.getEmployees(); 
    for ( this.index = 1; this.index < this.employees.length + 1; this.index++ ) {      
      this._route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
        this._id = +params.get('id')
        console.log('this index:', this.index); 
        this.employee = this._employeeService.getEmployee(this._id); 
      });   
    } 
  
  }


  viewNextEmployee() {
    if( this.index < this.employees.length ){
      this.index = this.index++;
      console.log('this index:', this.index); 
      this._router.navigate(['/team', this._id])
    } else {
      this.index = 1;
    }
  }

}
```

I'm sorry, I can't really reproduce a working code. So many dependencies.

Comment: The loop in the component is unclear. What exactly is the purpose of the loop? Each iteration would create a new subscription (that isn't closed at the moment BTW) and in each iteration the variable `this.employee` is written the same value. If there is a defined getter in the service using `Array#find`, why couldn't you do `this.employee = this._employeeService.getEmployee(+params.get('id'));` inside the subscription without the loop?

Comment: Where inside the getEmployee method? Wouldn't that be calling itself since this.employee = this._employeeService.getEmployee(+params.get('id')); calls this service method? I dont understand.

Comment: I'm sure the loops is wrong. Calling the getEmployee method to retrieve the ID is working. I am able to get the employee data on click from the parent component. I am also abel to read the index of the Array. What I can't figure out is (for every index lovation find the ID to send to the params so I can read the data from that param)